# SQL Query between three tables - which joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I’m trying to create a query in mySQL to select data from pre-existing tables on a database (Moodle to be specific). I realise that the scheme isn’t great, but this has come from the Moodle database with the ‘ratings’ plugin installed.

The current data structure looks like this:

**mdl_ranking_points**

```
CREATE TABLE `mdl_ranking_points` (
  `id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `courseid` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `points` decimal(10,1) NOT NULL,
  `timecreated` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `timemodified` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Points of users'
```

[image: mdl_ranking_points table]

**mdl_ranking_logs**

```
 CREATE TABLE `mdl_ranking_logs` (
      `id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `rankingid` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
      `courseid` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
      `course_modules_completion` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
      `points` decimal(10,1) NOT NULL,
      `timecreated` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Points of users'
```

[image: mdl_ranking_logs table]

**mdl_user**

```
 CREATE TABLE `mdl_user` (
      `id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `auth` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'manual',
      `confirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `idnumber` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `firstname` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `lastname` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `mdl_user_mneuse_uix` (`mnethostid`,`username`),
      KEY `mdl_user_fir_ix` (`firstname`),
      KEY `mdl_user_las_ix` (`lastname`),
      KEY `mdl_user_idn_ix` (`idnumber`),
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1045 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='One record for each person'
```

**mdl_course**

```
CREATE TABLE `mdl_course` (
  `id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sortorder` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fullname` varchar(254) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `shortname` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `idnumber` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `summary` longtext,
  `summaryformat` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `format` varchar(21) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'topics',
  `showgrades` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `newsitems` mediumint(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `startdate` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `enddate` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `marker` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `maxbytes` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `legacyfiles` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `showreports` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `visibleold` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `groupmode` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `groupmodeforce` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `defaultgroupingid` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lang` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `theme` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `timecreated` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timemodified` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `requested` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `enablecompletion` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `completionnotify` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cacherev` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `calendartype` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `mdl_cour_cat_ix` (`category`),
  KEY `mdl_cour_idn_ix` (`idnumber`),
  KEY `mdl_cour_sho_ix` (`shortname`),
  KEY `mdl_cour_sor_ix` (`sortorder`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Central course table';
```

I need to return a query with the following data:

lastname | points | average

I've tried the following query, but this doesnt return what I need (it seems that it only counts user id's that have been awarded points.

```
SELECT lastname AS academy,
    SUM(points) AS score,
    COUNT(*) AS users,
    (SUM(points)/COUNT(*)) AS norm
FROM mdl_ranking_points r
LEFT JOIN mdl_user ON r.userid = mdl_user.id
LEFT JOIN mdl_course ON r.courseid = mdl_course.id
GROUP BY lastname
ORDER BY norm DESC
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I may be approaching this completely the wrong way.

Comment: Can you provide the SHOW CREATE TABLE for mdl_course ?

Comment: @DanIonescu I have added to description. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, it would be useful if you could add an external download link with some sample sql to populate the tables. Trying to populate them manually on my test mysql would require a lot of time.

Comment: Telling us some columns and giving us a query that *isn't* what you want does not tell us what you want. You need to tell us when a row is in each table & in the query result. Ie give us those tables' *predicates*. Eg the query result holds rows where something like: "a person with last name *lastname* ... and *points* is ... and either they took no courses and *average* is NULL or their average is *average*". PS Please read & act on [mcve]. PPS Your query has different columns than you said you needed

Answer (score 1):

```
I've tried the following query, but this doesnt return what I need (it seems that it only counts user id's that have been awarded points.
```

This is because of the order in the joins. This will return all users even if they don't have rewarded some points

```
FROM mdl_user
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mdl_ranking_points
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mdl_course
```

Or change your query with a right outer join.

Comment: Thanks. But which field would I join mdl_ranking_points on, as it 'goes through' the mdl_ranking_logs table. I get the following error when running:

SELECT  
    lastname AS academy,
    SUM(points) AS score,
    COUNT(*) AS users,
    (SUM(points)/COUNT(*)) AS norm

FROM mdl_user u

LEFT OUTER JOIN mdl_ranking_points ON mdl_user.id = mdl_ranking_points.userid
LEFT OUTER JOIN mdl_course ON r.courseid = mdl_course.id

GROUP BY lastname
ORDER BY norm DESC

Unknown column 'mdl_user.id' in 'field list'

Comment: The message Unknown column 'mdl_user.id' in 'field list' is because you made an alias to the table mdl_user, so you have got to use the u in your further joins instead of the table name.